# dyld[39100]: Library not loaded: @rpath/Custom.framework/CustomframeworkName

Tags: swift, xcode

I use XCode version 15.2 and when I run my app I got this error

`dyld[39100]: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFDateHelper.framework/AFDateHelper Referenced from: <802DF8F3-FF9B-363F-A2CA-4BCA13647123> /Users/timmycole/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EA2028C4-B34C-40AB-B164-12D7B9A8E7B1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E2237F0A-5C48-4C43-9B39-9EE2F794A061/MyApp.app/MyApp Reason: tried: '/Users/timmycole/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-agvscnwhdjroathednqczxtegbmf/Build/Products/Staging-iphonesimulator/AFDateHelper.framework/AFDateHelper' (no such file), '/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/iOS_21A342/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 17.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/AFDateHelper.framework/AFDateHelper' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/AFDateHelper.framework/AFDateHelper' (no such file, no dyld cache),`.

but the file provided by this error is already existed in that specific directory. Can someone help me this problem.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with cocoapods, as it says, the library is not laoded. What helps me: closing the project and removing DerivedData folder. You might also try to run again `pod install` or go full cycle and deintegrate the pods first with `pod deintegrate. If you don't have pods, make sure that the library is linked in "Link Binary With Libraries". More info on how you integrate the 3rd party library would help to determine the exact issue, so please add that info to your question